# Vue js toogle the items in the list

Tags: vuejs2

I wanted to create a side menu bar. I have added a class `show` when the `li` should be shown.

But in my case what happen is when one item is shown(1st) and next(2nd) item is clicked, the 1st get collapsed(which is fine) but the 2nd do not show up immediately.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    setActiveItemId(itemIndex) {
      this.activeItemId = itemIndex
      this.isActive = !this.isActive
    }
  },
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    isActive: false,
    activeItemId: '',
    sideBar: [{
        name: "Dashboard",
        url: "/dashboard",
        icon: "ti-world",
        children: [{
            name: "Buttons",
            url: "/components/buttons",
            icon: "fa-book",
          },
          {
            name: "Social Buttons",
            url: "/components/social-buttons",
            icon: "icon-puzzle",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Components",
        url: "/components",
        icon: "ti-pencil-alt",
        children: [{
            name: "Buttons",
            url: "/components/buttons",
            icon: "fa-book",
          },
          {
            name: "Social Buttons",
            url: "/components/social-buttons",
            icon: "icon-puzzle",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.collapse.show {
  display: block;
}

.collapse {
  display: none;
}

.list-unstyled {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.collapse.list-unstyled {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>


<div id="app">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>
      <a>
        <i class="ti-home"></i>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li v-for="(x, itemIndex) in sideBar" :key="itemIndex">
      <a @click="setActiveItemId(itemIndex)">
        <i class="fa" :class="x.icon"></i>{{x.name}}
      </a>
      <ul :id="x.id" class="collapse list-unstyled" :class="{'show':activeItemId === itemIndex  && isActive}">
        <li v-for="y in x.children" :key="y.id">
          <a>{{y.name}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So, How can i collapse the 1st and display the 2nd immediately, when 2nd item is clicked?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2r6vej0/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that inside your `setActiveItemId` method you are always toggling the `isActive` state, regardless of which item is being activated. That means that it toggles the same item, but when jumping to another you'll have to click twice. I'd take a different approach, where `isActive` is a computed property instead of residing in the data.

```
// ...
methods: {
    setActiveItemId(itemIndex) {
        // If item is currently selected, toggle
        if (itemIndex === this.activeItemId) {
            this.activeItemId = ''
            return
        }
        this.activeItemId = itemIndex
    }
},
computed: {
    isActive () {
        return this.activeItemId !== ''
    }
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2ytuL46c/3/

Unrelated but worth noting: remember that your `data` must be a function that returns the data object, and not an object itself.

Comment: Your answer is working nice but now the problem i got is during the collapse  it looks so forcefully or looking something weird with my current css. https://jsfiddle.net/g16xftq2/6/

Comment: That's likely a problem with the CSS, not Vue. You can either update the fiddle so we can understand what's going on, or create another question as it is likely unrelated to the original problem.

Comment: I have added the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588960/vue-js-bootstrap-collapse-not-smooth